# TypeORM migration drop and add columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have an existing table in MySQL database named "users" ("login", "password") with existing columns.
When I try to create a migration using the command "migration:generate" TypeORM generates the migration and drops all columns and creates it like this again:

```
Users table DDL
create table if not exists users
(
    id                            int auto_increment primary key,
    login                         varchar(50)          not null,
    name                          varchar(255)         not null,
    surname                       varchar(50)          null,
    patronymic                    varchar(255)         null,
    mail                          varchar(255)         not null,
    phone                         varchar(255)         null,
    password                      varchar(255)         not null,
);
```

Migration

```
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`users\` DROP COLUMN \`login\``);
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`users\` DROP COLUMN \`password\``);
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`users\` ADD \`login\` varchar(50) NOT NULL`);
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`users\` ADD \`password\` varchar(255) NOT NULL`);
...
```

Entity

```
@Entity({
    name: 'users',
})
export class UserModel {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: TUserID;

    @Column({ length: 50, nullable: true })
    login: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({ length: 50, nullable: true })
    surname: string;

    @Column({ length: 50, nullable: true })
    patronymic: string;

    @Column({ length: 50 })
    mail: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

How can I fix this problem? I need to create an entity so that new migrations can be generated without deleting columns